# Prove that the directional derivative doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$p \geq 1, \,\,\,\, r_p: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto ||x||_p$ where $||.||_p$ is the $L^p$ norm.

Prove that the directional derivative of $r_p$ in the point $a=0$ in the direction $v \in \mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$ doesn't exist.

---

I have a different result:

$D_v(r_p(a)) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\sum |a_i+tv_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}-(\sum |a_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{t} = \lim\frac{(\sum |tv_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{t} = \lim\frac{(\sum |tv_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{t}$

Now we can "cut" the $t$ in the bottom with one $t$ in the sum (sorry I'm not English) and then this $\lim$ should exist, right?

So where's my mistake and how to solve this task instead?

Comment: "proof" is the noun, "to prove" is the verb. I corrected it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the numerator $|t|$ pulls out, not $t$. So you get $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {|t|} t \sum (|v_i|^{p})^{1/p}$ which does not exist since the right hand and left limits are different.